# How can I query entries related to another section’s entries having specific Matrix checkbox field values?

Tags: entries, matrix, entries-field, checkboxes

Let’s say I have a site with two sections: *Things* and *Colors*.

*Things* has a Matrix field (`thingsBlocks`) with a *Sizes* block type. That *Sizes* block type has a checkboxes field (`sizes`) with values that will be important again in a moment.

The *Colors* section has an entries field (`thingsEntries`) for relationships to *Things*.

**My goal** is to query *Colors* entries related to *Things* that have *Sizes* blocks with specific size values checked, and I’d like this to be an element query I can use with pagination.

The following pseudo-code is pure fantasy and does not work:

```
{% set colorsWithSizedThings = craft.entries()
  .section('colors')
  .thingsEntries(['thingsBlocks' => ['sizes' => ['sizeA', 'sizeD']])
  .all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, but you’ll need to break it into a few steps:

1. Get the Matrix blocks having the desired checked size values.
2. Get the IDs of the *Things* entries that own those Matrix blocks.
3. Get the *Colors* entries related to those *Things* entries by their IDs.

For context, we can quickly dump out our *Things* and their sizes along with our *Colors* and their related *Things*:

```
{# ------------------------------------------------------ #}
{# Establishing Context                                   #}
{# ------------------------------------------------------ #}

{% set things = craft.entries().section('things').all() %}
{% set colors = craft.entries().section('colors').all() %}

<h2>Things</h2>
<ul>
  {% for thing in things %}
    <li>
      {{ thing.title }}<br>
      {% for size in thing.thingsBlocks.type('sizes').one().sizes %}
        <code>✓ {{ size }}</code>
        {% if not loop.last %}<br>{% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<h2>Colors</h2>
<ul>
  {% for color in colors %}
    <li>
      {{ color.title }}<br>
      {% for thing in color.thingsEntries.all() %}
        <code>{{ thing.title }}</code>
        {% if not loop.last %}<br>{% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And the query might look something like this:

```
{# ------------------------------------------------------ #}
{# The Part with the Answer                               #}
{# ------------------------------------------------------ #}

<h2>Colors with Specifically-Sized Things</h2>

{# Specify the checkbox size values we want #}
{% set targetSizes = ['sizeA', 'sizeD'] %}

<p>Colors entries related to Things with {{ targetSizes|join(' or ') }}.</p>

{# 1+2. Get IDs of entries owning the Matrix blocks with our desired sizes #}
{% set targetThingsEntryIds = craft.matrixBlocks()
  .field('thingsBlocks')
  .type('sizes')
  .sizes(targetSizes)
  .select('ownerId')
  .column() %}

{# 3. Query Colors entries with relationships to the target Things entries #}
{% set colorsWithSizedThings = craft.entries()
  .section('colors')
  .thingsEntries(targetThingsEntryIds)
  .all() %}

{# Tersely output list of resulting entry titles #}
{{ ul(colorsWithSizedThings|map((entry) => "#{entry.title}")) }}
```

`colorsWithSizedThings` will work with [pagination](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/tags.html#paginate) like any other element query.

That `.sizes(targetSizes)` part will query either of the provided values (`or`). See the [Checkboxes Fields](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/checkboxes-fields.html#querying-elements-with-checkboxes-fields) page for other query options including treating the value array as an `and`—meaning all provided options must be checked rather than *any* of them.

---

**Edit 11/30/21**

Andrew demonstrated how to accomplish this using a custom behavior:
[Searching Craft CMS Matrix Blocks](https://nystudio107.com/blog/searching-craft-cms-matrix-blocks)